# How to compile and run "protoident"

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make, configure, makefile

I'm trying to compile and run an open-source DPI tool named *Protoident*. So I downloaded [its source code from Github](https://github.com/jwrona/protoident/tree/e18ff0eb2849593b9aad11978695d1f6ad514ae9) and searched inside the directories for compile/build manuals, but I found nothing. Finally I started by running `make` command and `Makefile` command inside its directory, but I faced the following errors:

```
me@me-MS-7693:~/Desktop/protoident-master/src$ ./Makefile 
./Makefile: line 9: TARGET: command not found
./Makefile: line 10: PROTOCOLS: command not found
./Makefile: line 11: PROTOCOLS: command not found
./Makefile: line 11: SOURCES: command not found
./Makefile: line 12: SOURCES:.c=.h: command not found
./Makefile: line 12: HEADERS: command not found
./Makefile: line 13: SOURCES:.c=.o: command not found
./Makefile: line 13: OBJECTS: command not found
./Makefile: line 14: OTHER_FILES: command not found
./Makefile: line 18: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 19: CFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 21: OFLAG: command not found
./Makefile: line 22: CFLAG: command not found
./Makefile: line 24: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 24: LINK: command not found
./Makefile: line 25: LINKFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 26: LIBS: command not found
./Makefile: line 31: .SUFFIXES:: command not found
./Makefile: line 32: .c.o:: command not found
./Makefile: line 33: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 33: CFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 33: CFLAG: command not found
./Makefile: line 33: OFLAG: command not found
./Makefile: line 33: $<: command not found
./Makefile: line 38: SOURCES: command not found
./Makefile: line 38: TARGET: command not found
./Makefile: line 38: all:: command not found
./Makefile: line 40: profile:: command not found
./Makefile: line 41: profile_compile:: command not found
./Makefile: line 42: profile_compile:: command not found
./Makefile: line 43: profile_compile:: command not found
./Makefile: line 46: TARGET: command not found
./Makefile: line 46: OBJECTS: command not found
./Makefile: line 47: LINK: command not found
./Makefile: line 47: LINKFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 47: LIBS: command not found
./Makefile: line 47: OFLAG: command not found
./Makefile: line 47: TARGET: command not found
./Makefile: line 47: OBJECTS: command not found
./Makefile: line 52: archive:: command not found
./Makefile: line 53: TARGET: command not found
./Makefile: line 53: SOURCES: command not found
./Makefile: line 53: HEADERS: command not found
./Makefile: line 53: OTHER_FILES: command not found
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
./Makefile: line 55: clean:: command not found
./Makefile: line 56: OBJECTS: command not found
./Makefile: line 58: distclean:: command not found
./Makefile: line 59: TARGET: command not found


me@me-MS-7693:~/Desktop/protoident-master/src$ make
gcc  -lpcap -o protoident main.o hashtable.o ip_reassembling.o flow.o global_func.o dns.o http.o sip.o smtp.o
main.o: In function `main':
/home/ghasemi/Desktop/protoident-master/src/main.c:85: undefined reference to `pcap_open_offline'
/home/ghasemi/Desktop/protoident-master/src/main.c:97: undefined reference to `pcap_compile'
/home/ghasemi/Desktop/protoident-master/src/main.c:100: undefined reference to `pcap_geterr'
/home/ghasemi/Desktop/protoident-master/src/main.c:103: undefined reference to `pcap_setfilter'
/home/ghasemi/Desktop/protoident-master/src/main.c:105: undefined reference to `pcap_geterr'
/home/ghasemi/Desktop/protoident-master/src/main.c:118: undefined reference to `pcap_datalink'
/home/ghasemi/Desktop/protoident-master/src/main.c:125: undefined reference to `pcap_loop'
/home/ghasemi/Desktop/protoident-master/src/main.c:134: undefined reference to `pcap_freecode'
/home/ghasemi/Desktop/protoident-master/src/main.c:136: undefined reference to `pcap_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'protoident' failed
make: *** [protoident] Error 1
```

Why I faced those errors and how can I compile and use this tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Makefile` is a configuration file for `make`, not a separate command. The canonical [build & install procedure](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/27.html) is:

```
./configure
make
make install   # usually: sudo make install
```

Most projects describe their installation process in detail in text files `README`, `INSTALL` or similar.

However, this one does not have any `configure` script and has a ready `Makefile` instead. It does not contain `INSTALL` section, so the third command is also not applicable.

So you only have to run:

```
make
```

It is documented in the `README` file in the `src` directory. Funny is that it’s written in Czech (which is by the way my native language).

**Fixing `undefined reference` errors**

There is a problem in the provided Makefile that can be fixed using the following patch (based on a [Stack Overflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167588/undefined-reference-to-pcap#comment50344419_31167588)):

```
diff --git a/src/Makefile b/src/Makefile
index 367dcc4..dda5fb3 100644
--- a/src/Makefile
+++ b/src/Makefile
@@ -44,7 +44,7 @@ profile_compile: all


 $(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
-       $(LINK) $(LINKFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(OFLAG) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
+       $(LINK) $(LINKFLAGS) $(OFLAG) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

 #####################################
 #other rules
```

Comment: The command `./configure` in the `src` directory, returns `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Abraham Sorry, I had not explored the specific project enough. Instructions added now.

Comment: Thank you. You are welcome. As you see in the question, I also tried `make` command. But I received a bunch of `undefined reference` notifications and finally an error indicated `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'protoident' failed
make: *** [protoident] Error 1`.

Comment: I read the article `build & install procedure` you linked in your answer. It's great, thank you, now I understand what's happening. But still I can't finish the compilation.

Comment: `libpcap-dev` is already installed!

Comment: @Abraham Fixed finally, at least on my machine! See update.

Answer (score 1):

I took at look at your link for instructions. They can be found but are written in Czech. For example:

```
Zdrojová a cílová síťová adresa, zdrojový a cílový port není třeba dále
vysvětlovat.
```

Translates into English as:

```
Source and destination network address, source and destination port does not need to be further explain.
```

Looking at various source files you'll see "Not Tested" in the description.

This author calls the project an experiment and it has not been updated in 2 years.

I propose the project is broken and there may be nothing wrong with your compiler and make functions. To confirm your system is working download a simple calculator from github for gnome desktop that has 200 contributors and 243 releases: [gnome-calculator](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-calculator). Compile this instead of your current choice that has no activity for two years and is called an experiment by the author.